# Pass links as variable in php and echo it on html

Tags: php, html

i must pass multiple link as variables on php
ex: `www.mysite.com/dl.php?link=www.google.com&link2=yahoo.com&link3=youtube.com` and so on, there is a variable number of links, and then i want to put them on and html page generated dynamically based on the number of links i inputed, in the example i did, the links was 3, so it must be:

```
<html><center>
<a href="<?php echo $_link ?>">Click to download part 1</a>
<a href="<?php echo $_link1 ?>">Click to download part 2</a>
<a href="<?php echo $_link2 ?>">Click to download part 3</a>
</center></html>
```

can someone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If URL = www.mysite.com/dl.php?link1=www.google.com&link2=yahoo.com&link3=youtube.com

```
<?php
for($i = 0; $i < count($_GET); $i++)
{
?>
<a href="<?php echo $_GET["link".($i+1)]; ?>">Click to download part <?php echo ($i+1);?></a>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: There is no need to provide the number of links. You can just count them with count($_GET)

Answer (score 2):

Parameters you append on your URL can be accessed through `$_GET` in php. 
Take a look at this page: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

**Update:** If you have a variable number of get parameters and you want to get them all just use a foreach loop:

```
foreach($_GET as $key => $url) {
 echo $url;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using different parameter names for all urls, use an array:

```
www.mysite.com/dl.php?link[]=www.google.com&link[]=yahoo.com&link[]=youtube.com
```

Then, in `dl.php`, `$_GET['link']` is an array. You can iterate like this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_GET['link']); ++$i) {
  echo '<a href="' . $_GET['link'][$i] . '">Click to download part ' . ($i + 1) . '</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the only get value that is the URLs then just loop through...

```
foreach ($_GET as $url)
    {
    echo $url
    }
```